# PHP & Mysql bulk selected data and update all selected data with one html form

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can I select some MySQL data from an HTML table? And how can I update all selected data with one HTML update form?

I thought with using a checkbox I can select some data, but how can I update the all selected data with one update form?

Example:

```
--- ------------------------
id | name | phone| Address|
----------------------------
1  | HSSSS| 57883|        |
----------------------------
2  | BBBBB| 97668|        |
----------------------------
3  | CCCCC| 23454|        |
----------------------------
4  | CCCCC| 23454|        |
----------------------------
```

You can see in the table address column has no data. Now suppose 2, 3, 4 number ids `data[address]` I selected. So, how can I update the all selected data with one HTML update form?

Comment: post code with your question what you try .its usefull to give answers

Comment: you want update same address for every selected person or each one different address ?

Comment: yes i want to update same address for every selected person with a html update form, so i  need the php mysql script for do that

Answer (score 0):

Adding a checkbox to each table row is a good way to go.

You need to solve this yourself, but here are some hints:

- Use the id of the row either within the name of the checkbox or as it's value.
- Dump (show) the incoming arguments in your PHP script to see what you get.
- Check the mySQL manual for the *UPDATE* command: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html
- The *WHERE* argument may be used with a *IN* expression, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm for details
- Always use placeholders, never insert any values in a SQL query!

Answer (score 0):

first form should be like this

**list.php**

```html
list.php

here you select using checkbox whoever you want edit. all the id are stored in user_ids[] array .

 <form action="update.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="user_ids[]" value="1" > 
<input type="checkbox" name="user_ids[]" value="2" > 
<input type="checkbox" name="user_ids[]" value="3" > 
<input type="submit" name="list" value="submit" >
</form>


then here we received those ids and set into hidden field and fill the address field and submit and your query should be like this .

update.php

<?php
 
 if(isset($_POST['update']))
 {
   
   $ids = implode(',',$_POST['update_user_ids']);
  
   //$conn //your connection variable
   mysql_query($conn,"update your_table_name set address='".$_POST['address']."' where id IN(".$ids.")");
  
 }
 else
 {

  ?>
  <form action="update.php" method="post">

  <?php foreach($_POST['user_ids'] as $row){
   
  ?>

  <input type="hidden" name="update_user_ids[]"  value="<?php echo $row; ?>" >

  <?php 
   
  }

  ?>
  <textarea name="address" ></textarea>

  <input type="submit" name="update" value="submit" >


  </form>

 <?php  
 }
  
 ?>
```